# Using QField with Trimble DA2 on iOS

Tags: qfield, trimble

Is there a way to use the da2 with QField on an iPhone? Am I only able to connect the da2 via Bluetooth with an Android phone?

Comment: There is a QField app for iOS, macOS and of course Android.

Comment: I have the Qfield app for iOS but there doesn’t seem to be an option for me to connect to the da2 via Bluetooth. The only 2 options it’s showing is TCP and UDP. So cannot I not use Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

DA2 definitely does work with iOS.

Have a look at the information on [the Trimble web site](https://geospatial.trimble.com/products-and-solutions/trimble-da2) - essentially, once you pair the iOS device with the DA2 and connect to it, positions will feed to the iOS Location Services from the DA2, so you get DA2 positions instead of positions from the internal GNSS on your device.

Comment: You must use Trimble Mobile Manager - ttps://apps.apple.com/us/app/trimble-mobile-manager/id1477956695

Answer (score 0):

Usually apps let you choose between internal device that meand the built-in gps inside you Iphone o ipad, and give's you the option to select a external device and usually you can choose the name like DA2. The fact that Qfield show you only the internal device scared me. It's not user friendly the user interface...
Why should be different from all the others apps? As i said, in other apps even if you are connected via BT with the trimble mobile manager, you still have the option to choose between internal and external device for positioning. And internal it's always been the low quality gps from your phone/tablet